# How put Dataframe into one cell as list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

i'm trying to put a dataframe as list in one cell in R, but when i try to do i get a warning msg and only is saved the first column

```
library(tidyverse)

list1 <- list(A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1")   # Create first example list
list1     

list2 <- list(A = "A2", B = "B2", C = "C2")   # Create second example list
list2 

list12 <- Map(c, list1, list2) %>% as.data.frame()             # Merge two lists
list12

Test_ <- "Row1" %>% as.data.frame()
Test_$list[1] <- list12
```

This is the error

```
Warning message:
In Test_$list[1] <- list12 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I want to have something like this, have a kind of subtable into my dataframe:
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `list` on the object `list12` which is a `data.frame`

```
Test_$list[1] <- list(list12)
```